# Order Multidimensional Arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some problem to order an array by a field of this, here i leave the example

```
foreach($xml as $site){
echo '<div><a href="'.$site->loc.'">'.$site->loc.'</a>' .$site->padre.'</div>';
}
```

Some times the filed `$site->padre` is empty but i'd like to order by `$site->padre` alphabetical
i saw example with usort but i don't understand how to work it.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

   function alphabetize($a, $b){
     # property notation as used in original question
     return strcmp($a->padre, $b->padre);
   }

   $xml = uasort($xml, 'alphabetize');
   foreach($xml as $site){
     # your code here
   }

?>
```

Alternatively, you can use a lambda function using PHP's [`create_function()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

```
$xml = uasort($xml, create_function('$a,$b', 'return strcmp($a->padre, $b->padre);'));
```

Or, if you have PHP >= 5.3

```
$xml = uasort($xml, function($a,$b){ return strcmp($a->padre, $b->padre); });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a['padre'], $b['padre']);
}

usort($xml, "cmp");
foreach($xml as $site){
    echo '<div><a href="'.$site->loc.'">'.$site->loc.'</a>' .$site->padre.'</div>';
}
```

The cmp function will be called for every element in the array. The function must return an integer to determine if $a is more, less or equal to $b. Specifying ['padre'] in the cmp function will compare that element.

Comment: If you wish to maintain the index association in your $xml array, then use uasort instead of usort.